# Xamarin Google Play Services

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I use google play services and try to make a  daily Leaderboard. But, using the method "Submit score ()", the record is written to all tables (Daily, All_Time, Weekly). How can I record a user's score only in the Daily Leaderboard?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Daily leaderboards reset at midnight PST every day, and weekly leaderboards reset at Saturday midnight PST.

The scores that you post automatically will update Daily, Weekly and All Time leaderboards. During the *first* day of posting the *first* score that score in turn is the highest for all three boards. As time progresses the scores posted are bucketed based upon the **reset times** for each board.

- https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards

Comment: Yes, I also read it. But in Submitscore there is no specification of what kind of score.

Comment: @Rollinart That is a different question, when you create a leaderboard, you define the type: Numeric, Time, or Currency leaderboard. Depending upon the type of leaderboard the value that you submit is viewed differently, consult the `Score formatting` in that link

Comment: There's not what I need. I found something similar in Api Overview / Scores / Submit https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/scores/submit
But I do not have a parameter `consistencyToken long` in my method `Submit`

Comment: No one knows how to achieve this?